# How to translate ActiveStorage attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n, rails-activestorage

My model, Order, has many texts, and each text can have one attached document (`has_one_attached(:document)`).
Sometimes, the base error is `Texts document`, sometimes `document`...

I would like to translate it, but I don't know how.

This is my `activerecord.fr.yml` :

```
fr:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        text:
          attributes:
            document: 'blabla'
            texts_document: 'test'
```

but it's not working. I also tried this:

```
fr:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        order:
          attributes:
            texts:
             document: 'blabla'
             texts_document: 'test'
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fr:
  activerecord:
    models:
      order: "l'ordre"
      text: le texte
    attributes:
      text:
        document: le document
```